# How decode windowsCP1251 percent encoded String ? Swift 4 ios 11

Tags: string, decode, ios11, swift4, cp1251

How to decode String from percent encoded windowsCP1251?

replacingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.windowsCP1251) now is obsolete

removingPercentEncoding uses utf8

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. It works for me. Welcome to refactor my example.

```
extension String {
    func removingPercentEncoding(using encoding: String.Encoding) -> String {
        let firstChar = self.first
        let percentCharacter = Character("%")

        var encodedPrefix: String.SubSequence? = nil
        var encodedSuffix = self
        if firstChar != percentCharacter {
            if let indexOfFirstPercentChar = index(of: percentCharacter) {
                encodedPrefix = self[..<indexOfFirstPercentChar]
                encodedSuffix = String(self[indexOfFirstPercentChar...])
            } else {
                //no % char at all. Nothing encoded
                return self
            }
        }

        let substrings = encodedSuffix.components(separatedBy: "%")
        let arr = substrings.map{ substring -> (String) in
            switch substring.count {
            case let count where count < 2:
                return substring
            case let count where count == 2:
                let decodedArr = substring.hexa2Bytes
                let data = Data(decodedArr)
                if let decodedStr = String(data: data, encoding: encoding) {
                    return decodedStr
                }

                return substring
            default: //>2
                let thirdSymbolIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
                let firstTwo = substring[..<thirdSymbolIndex]
                let furhter = substring[thirdSymbolIndex...]
                let decodedArr = String(firstTwo).hexa2Bytes
                let data = Data(decodedArr)
                if let decodedStr = String(data: data, encoding: encoding) {
                    return decodedStr + furhter
                }

                return substring
            }
        }

        let result = arr.joined()

        return String(encodedPrefix ?? "") + result
    }

    var hexa2Bytes: [UInt8] {
        let hexa = Array(characters)
        return stride(from: 0, to: characters.count, by: 2).flatMap { UInt8(String(hexa[$0..<$0.advanced(by: 2)]), radix: 16) }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little example which is expected to work with multi-byte string encodings.

```
extension UInt8 {
    //returns 0...15 when '0'...'9', 'A'...'F', 'a'...'f', otherwise returns nil
    var hexValue: UInt8? {
        if UInt8(ascii: "0") <= self && self <= UInt8(ascii: "9") {
            return self - UInt8(ascii: "0")
        } else if UInt8(ascii: "A") <= self && self <= UInt8(ascii: "F") {
            return self - UInt8(ascii: "A") + 10
        } else if UInt8(ascii: "a") <= self && self <= UInt8(ascii: "f") {
            return self - UInt8(ascii: "a") + 10
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    func removingPercentEncoding(using encoding: String.Encoding) -> String? {
        guard let percentEncodedData = self.data(using: encoding) else {return nil}
        var byteIterator = percentEncodedData.makeIterator()
        var percentDecodedData = Data()
        while let b0 = byteIterator.next() {
            guard b0 == UInt8(ascii: "%"), let b1 = byteIterator.next() else {
                //Non percent character
                percentDecodedData.append(b0)
                continue
            }
            guard let h1 = b1.hexValue, let b2 = byteIterator.next() else {
                //Keep it as is, when invalid hex-sequece appeared
                percentDecodedData.append(b0)
                percentDecodedData.append(b1)
                continue
            }
            guard let h2 = b2.hexValue else {
                //Keep it as is, when invalid hex-sequece appeared
                percentDecodedData.append(b0)
                percentDecodedData.append(b1)
                percentDecodedData.append(b2)
                continue
            }
            percentDecodedData.append((h1<<4) + h2)
        }
        return String(data: percentDecodedData, encoding: encoding)
    }
}
```

---

In my opinion, you should think **non-UTF8 percent encoding *now is obsolete***, and should fix the part which is generating the percent encoded string with CP1251.